# Email displaying one letter per row

Tags: html, email, templates, gmail, mjml

I am new to email templates and am using MJML to create a template which a client is in the process of testing, and they have responded showing a screen shot of the email text displaying vertically (one letter per row).

When personally testing the emails in Gmail, they appear as expected, so I am assuming it is a browser or email service issue.

Is there a way to ensure the email content gets displayed the same on all email services?

Comment: Can you provide an example of MJML code that you have tried?

Comment: It sounds like your column width has collapsed. If you could post your code then people would be able to help you out further.